# React how to use setState with Map value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm at a loss here. Here is the relevant code I have:

```
const TraitModal = (props) => {
const [abiltiesChecked, setAbiltiesChecked] = React.useState(new Map());
const handleAbilitiesCheck = (e) => {
        var newabilitiesCH=abiltiesChecked.set(e.target.id, e.target.checked);
        setAbiltiesChecked(newabilitiesCH);
    };
return(
<Form>
GetAbilities().map((a) => (
                                        <div key={`custom-${a}-2`}>
                                            <Form.Check
                                                custom
                                                checked={!!abiltiesChecked.get(`abilities-${a}`)}
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                id={`abilities-${a}`}
                                                label={`${a}`}
                                                onChange={handleAbilitiesCheck.bind(this)}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
</Form>
    );
    }
```

---

---

In my understanding the setAbiltiesChecked(newabilitiesCH) replaces the old abiltiesChecked and thus would cause the React component to rerender, however that's not whats happening at all. The state does get updated as I figured out with some console logs, but it does not get updated from handleAbilitiesCheck function.

I have another function that basically rerenders on a input into a text box and that triggers a rerendering of the checkboxes, but I need them to show that the checkbox was actually clicked, whats the error with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mutating your stateful object (your call to state changes the current map object), then assigning to it. React performs a diff on the object, sees no change, and therefore does not re-render.

In this specific case, replace:

```js
    var newabilitiesCH=abiltiesChecked.set(e.target.id, e.target.checked);
```

with

```js
    var newabilitiesCH= new Map(abiltiesChecked).set(e.target.id, e.target.checked);
```

The new copy should be recognized by React as a new state.