# html not re-rendering after prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have template in form of a table where I am updating a column based on a button click which is supposed to change the `props`. Even though the `props` are getting updated I don't see the template re-render.
However since I am also caching values for other rows in `translatedMessageMap` the properly gets rendered on the next button click ie next `prop` update for another row.

```
// components/Chat/TableDownload.tsx
import classNames from 'classnames' // classNames to organize the classes.
import { FC, memo, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { ChatMessageModel } from '~types'
import ChatMessageCard from './ChatMessageCard'
import Button from '../Button'

let translatedMessageMap = new Map<string, ChatMessageModel>;

interface Props {
  files: any[]
  onSubmit: (value: string) => void
  lastmessage?: ChatMessageModel
}

const TableDownload = (props: Props) => {
  const [engContentText, setEngContentText] = useState('bla bla text')
  const [translatingLocale, setTranslatingLocale] = useState('')

  const translateIt = (loc: string) => {
    setTranslatingLocale(loc)
    props.onSubmit("translate the following: " + engContentText)
  }
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.lastmessage){
      translatedMessageMap.set(translatingLocale, props.lastmessage)
      console.log(props.lastmessage);//<---------- here I can see prop.lastmessage has indeed changed
    }
  }, [props.lastmessage])


  if (props.files.length) {
    return (
      <div className="relative overflow-x-auto">
          <table>
              <tbody>
                {
                  (() => {
                    let container:any[] = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < props.files.length; i++) {
                      container.push(
                        <tr key={i}>
                          <th scope="row">
                              {props.files[i].name}
                          </th>
                          <td>
                              {props.files[i].webkitRelativePath.replace('_locales/', '').replace('/messages.json', '')}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <Button text="Transate it" onClick={() => translateIt(props.files[i].webkitRelativePath.replace('_locales/', '').replace('/messages.json', ''))}/>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {(() => {
                              let _loc = props.files[i].webkitRelativePath.replace('_locales/', '').replace('/messages.json', '')
                              let existingMessage = translatedMessageMap.get(_loc)
                              if (existingMessage)
                                return <ChatMessageCard key={existingMessage?.id} message={existingMessage}/>
                              else if (_loc === translatingLocale && props.lastmessage)
                                return <ChatMessageCard key={props.lastmessage.id} message={props.lastmessage}/>
                              else
                                return "NA"
                            })()}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      )
                    }
                    return container;
                  })()
                }
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <></>
    );
  }
}

export default TableDownload
```

Ideally I would like to just fillup `translatedMessageMap` and display at once and don't need to handle

`<ChatMessageCard key={existingMessage?.id} message={existingMessage}/>` and

`<ChatMessageCard key={props.lastmessage.id} message={props.lastmessage}/>` separately

Secondly `translatedMessageMap` should be a `useState` too but not being able to get the exact syntax I kept it as a global variable.

I believe it is due to function
`(() => {})()`

**when I use raw {prop.lastmessage.text} it works fine.**

Comment: if you need to rerender when `translatedMessageMap` changes, then you need to make it a state. react doesn't know when a global variable changes, and will not rerender in response to that.

Comment: @nullptr I am having hard time putting state on `Map` . can you help me with correct syntax for that.

Comment: @nullptr also I believe it is due to function `(() => {})()` that I have declared.

when I use raw `{prop.lastmessage.text}` it works fine.

Comment: `const [translatedMessageMap, setTranslatedMessageMap] = useState(new Map<string, ChatMessageModel>());`

Comment: @nullptr now how do you add to it ? `setTranslatedMessageMap ` would mean I have to set the entire map. isn't it ? I need to add one new value for one new key.

Comment: @nullptr I tried `setTranslatedMessageMap([..translatedMessageMap, {newKey, newValue}])`, but I dont think this is correct.

Comment: yes, you will have to recreate the map if you want to set the state

Answer (score 0):

Changing `translatedMessageMap` from global variable to use `useState` sufficed:

```
  const [translatedMessageMap, setTranslatedMessageMap] = useState(new Map<string, ChatMessageModel>());
```

then Updating as:

```
  let newTranslatedMessageMap = new Map(translatedMessageMap).set(translatingLocale, props.lastmessage);
  setTranslatedMessageMap(newTranslatedMessageMap)
```

then in the arrow funtion within html
omiting the else clause coresponding to `<ChatMessageCard key={props.lastmessage.id} message={props.lastmessage} className={'mt-5'} />`

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163326/865220) helped me on figuring out the correct syntax on how to update the map.